# Removing duplicated animation attributes in Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, androidx, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

Is it possible to get rid of the code duplication in the navigation graph in the situation where multiple `actions` have exactly the same animations?

Here is an example:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/loginMethod"
    android:name="com.package.LoginMethodFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login_method">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_loginMethod_to_email"
        app:destination="@id/email"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_loginMethod_to_password"
        app:destination="@id/password"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
</fragment>
```

Basically I'm looking for a method which allows me to declare all four `app:*Anim` attributes in one place and apply to both `actions`.
In the case of layouts, I can extract style with duplicated attributes. Does Navigation Component have a similar concept?